# How to disable filtering in telerik grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

Currently i am using Telerik grid which filters are applied to each column. I am binding the SQL result set to grid. If the result set is empty from the database while binding, I should disable the filter option in the grid.

How can i achive the same through ASPX or Code behind using C#. Does Telerik Grid have any property to disable the filtering option when thre are no records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check on the databound event of the grid if Items > 0, if not you would do

`grid.AllowFilteringByColumn = false;`